# Como puedo hacer una suma de un double y un string en Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

quisiera saber si alguien puede apoyarme ya que tengo 2 datos , uno ya viene como Double y el otro viene como string : ya intente meterlo en Double() pero a la hora de que muestra en pantalla solo me muestra el dato que viene en Double() y no la suma con el dato que viene en string

```
Text("\(self.viewModel.accountReportData?.getFinalBalance() ?? 0 +  (Double(positionDetailsData.cash ?? "0.00") ?? 0.00)) MXN")
```

Este es mi componente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece ser algo del compilador (opinión), porque lo he revisado hasta en modo `debug` y no lo suma. Pero si colocas entre paréntesis el primer valor si funciona:

```
Text("\((self.viewModel.accountReportData?.getFinalBalance() ?? 0) +  (Double(positionDetailsData.cash ?? "0.00") ?? 0.00)) MXN")
```

De igual manera si separas los valores en otras variables funciona:

```
let num1 = self.viewModel.accountReportData?.getFinalBalance() ?? 0
let num2 = (Double(positionDetailsData.cash ?? "0.00") ?? 0.00)

Text("\(num1 + num2)")
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias amigo , con esto pude saludos